# Support for navigator.geolocation change event

Tags: javascript, geolocation, dom-events

It would be awesome to be able to attach a listener to a change in geolocation.

I haven't been able to find anything commenting on this either on [w3](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) or searching elsewhere. Seems that its obviously not provided at the moment, but is there any planned support for this from any browser or any w3 spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This method returns a watch ID value then can be used to unregister the handler by passing it to the Geolocation.clearWatch() method." 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition

```
id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options)
```

http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#watch-position

Awesome stuff. Thanks.